# Trigonometric Substitution and the Triangle Inequality

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I was reading the solution to this problem:

If $x, y, z$ are real numbers and $x+y+z=xyz$ then

$x(1 − y^2 )(1 − z^2 ) + y(1 − z^2 )(1 − x^2 ) + z(1 − x^2 )(1 − y^2 ) = 4xyz$

The solution is to divide both sides by $xyz$. Observing the resemblance to the tan double angle formula, the proof substitutes $x = \tan A, y = \tan B, z = \tan C$ where A, B,C are angles of a triangle. Later on, the proof uses the fact that $A+B+C=\pi$.

But if $A,B, $and $  C$ are angles of the same triangle it follows that the triangle inequality must hold. This puts a restriction on the values of $x, y$, and $z$ that is not specified in the problem statement. The proof, therefore, is not valid for all real numbers $x, y$, and $z$.

Source: Putnam and Beyond pg 239

Comment: $x$ is $\tan A$, not triangle's side. Triangle's angle can be anything, so can its tan.

Comment: Ignoring triangles, one reason it could equal $\pi$ might be that if $\tan(A)+\tan(B)+\tan(C)=0$ then $A,B,C=n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (I know that it can be true without them all being multiples of $\pi$ but ignore that). Would the rest of the proof work with $A+B+C=n\pi$ instead of $\pi$?

Comment: @Kaster The angles can be anything, but there's no guarantee that the angles form a valid triangle.

Comment: @user1299784, Restriction on the $x,y,z$ guarantees that, I suppose.

Comment: @oliveeuler I made a mistake in the OP - $x+y+z = xyz$,  not  $0$

Comment: @Kaster $x+y+z = xyz$ - I made a mistake in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

One can simply prove

$(x(1-y^2)(1-z^2)+y(1-x^2)(1-z^2)+z(1-x^2)(1-y^2)-4xyz) = (yz+xz+xy-1)(xyz-z-y-x)$

thus your long equation is zero with the help of $(xyz-z-y-x)=0$ your condition.

Comment: I think question here is "Why using triangles is valid?", and not "How to solve it alternatively?".

Comment: But I find it very irritating and artificial for such an easy proof to use some extra function which could result in extra problems.

Comment: Believe or not, but what you referring as "one can simply prove" is very hard to foresee. Unless you saw it somewhere else before.

Comment: Come on! That is a polynomial long division with $(xyz-z-y-x)$.

Comment: Why would you long divide on to another? :)

Comment: How would you show "$g=0$ implies $f=0$" with $f,g$ both polynomials?